# Add props to Button in Mantine TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mantine

I would like to create a button that changes background color depending on what the page/path is.

To do this, I was thinking of passing a new prop (ex. `selected`) to the `Button` component in Mantine in TypeScript.

So far, I have tried extending the interface to include the default passed params:

```
interface ButtonProps extends ButtonStylesParams {
  selected?: boolean;
}

const AboutItem = styled(Button)<ButtonProps>`
  color: white;
  background-color: ${props => props.selected ? "#282828" : "transparent"};
`;
```

However, this gives me an error when I try and use the `AboutItem` component:

```
Type '{ children: string; selected: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { theme?: Theme | undefined; } & ButtonProps'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { theme?: Theme | undefined; } & ButtonProps'
```

I'm wondering what the correct way of doing this is?

Comment: What is `ButtonStylesParams`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Mantine docs about [styled polymorphic components](https://mantine.dev/styles/styled/#polymorphic-components):

> Emotion cannot correctly extract prop types from [polymorphic components](https://mantine.dev/guides/polymorphic/). To add styles to such components with `@emotion/styled`, you will need to redefine polymorphic component type with [`createPolymorphicComponent` function](https://mantine.dev/guides/polymorphic/#create-your-own-polymorphic-components)

```
import { Button, createPolymorphicComponent } from '@mantine/core';

const StyledAboutItem = createPolymorphicComponent<'button', ButtonProps>(AboutItem);

() => (
    // Okay
    <StyledAboutItem selected={true}>
        Some children
    </StyledAboutItem>
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgCEBXGGCAOwBo40iUYkABQgAbAJ4hoYABbA0AYVyR2SdvAC+cbLjgByAAIgUa4CoD0aaEl0Uq0eAGcYYkUgAmWnHgNJJMYBxmTi7uNuSUakhQmOhIjCxs7II4YA5wZgBUSAAeAuxuacysHADKzq4OgihQKCAOGWZ05HAtcA5IrhjuAPwAXHAARhCiqOwU6uGW7E5wAIJDLACSAngAvG3l7gAURYkAlHAAPLscyRCpAHwABs08otD9AO6yAhQtA+gA1gDmOEz5AFpLCIHnAACS0MApNKrC5wKHnBwAOnanQEHm6BAAxAAmAAc+Px+Dg-XwMBq0zA1VUMHw6goVwo5C2B1hcC2txaZkaAFEoDgoP0zmAos49GhZCI3ER2Lo4G4IEg0uwIPAcsAZhw4M4RXpFmooKYHHJZqxDQMWEq4AAyOja6S+JB9OAAFQdIDiAB84P83EhMKZ3KQ4JpbScktDdEjOUd5hAlis2h0kF03KtaOSmEh1BcSrg4hLgFKZYczHGE74LuQ9kypjMyiE3OWYMtfHB1rxUAJhOJJFAZHJFOAODTDroLcVZdxw8KHBcts3WyAa+EWe24RzWulGgB5T4oMQxw4N1xNhYtxOolPo9OZ7O5-M8SXS1Slk-uRcrKsroA)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is possible to do the same using a Mantine component? For example, I tried doing a variation of this with Autocomplete `createPolymorphicComponent<typeof Autocomplete, NewInputProps>(StyledTextInput);` but I get the error message `'Autocomplete' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Autocomplete'?`

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this for [`Autocomplete`](https://mantine.dev/core/autocomplete/)? It does not look like a polymorphic component, on the contrary of [Button](https://mantine.dev/core/button/#polymorphic-component).